# Port Forwarding Issues in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, network-programming

I am trying to make a simple chat client application for a school assignment.

However the packets are being blocked by the router. I was suggested using UPNP to forward ports but the thing is that my i don't think i would be able allowed to use such a program due to security issues.

Are there any alternatives to UPNP for port forwarding one those can be used in a school setting, if i use UDP instead of TCP will i still need to forward port.

In the end i just want to achieve a simple transmission of messages over internet.

ADD: and i forgot to mention that i as a constraint for the project i cannot use anything non-microsoft.

Comment: Perhaps you are expected to run a server someplace, and communicate over a non-blocked port?

Comment: @ChadRuppert I don't know. A messenger type application is being demanded from me.

Comment: If you need help figuring out what *your* assignment is than at least post school name/teacher's name... Consider understanding what your assignment is before trying to implement it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Port Forwarding has nothing to do with C# or .NET - its a feature of the router to forward outside connection through a specific port to the internal address on the network.

Port forwarding is usually an issue with TCP/ip sockets (remoting). It is usually not an issue with webservices, they use standard protocols and go through the port 80, which is used by browsers.

If port forwarding is an issue, perhaps you should switch from TCP/IP to WebServices for your communication solution.

Comment: Thanks i guess, i will do further research into it.

Answer (score 3):

In applications like MSNMessager and Skype you have two applications running. First is the client which you run on your local computer and the second one is the server, which is running on the network of the provider. Most firewalls block only inbound connection requests and allow all outbound requests to go unfiltered. This is not always true, but in most cases it is. Clients applications will create the connection going outbound to the server, thus not restricted by the firewall.

MSNMessager does not connect directly to another client, but is handled and forward by a server applications. Once connected via TCP you stay connected until you decide to disconnect. Once connected two way communication can happen between the client and the server it is connected to.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

If you're entirely local to the machine you usually don't go through the firewall, so it shouldn't be an issue.  If you need to talk with different machines your network admin will likely need to open a hole in the firewall for you.  Talk to your teacher about the issue; perhaps a port is already opened for this purpose, or perhaps he doesn't expect you to need to get around the firewall in the first place.

If the question is basically, "how do I hack my way around my school's firewall" then my answer would be, "don't".  That would be a malicious application.

Comment: its not a malicious application its a chat client that i need to demonstrate to my teacher allowing communication through internet. My teacher is non cooperative on the issue. He says the app must function in the school environment. and do you mean that regardless of the protocol used i will still have the firewall to contend with ?

Comment: @WinCoder I'm saying that if your application isn't malicious then you shouldn't need to bypass the firewall in the first place.  If you're saying that you *must* hack through your firewall then it *would* be malicious.  I highly doubt that your teacher would give you an assignment that required you do something your school's firewall is prohibiting.  `do you mean that regardless of the protocol used i will still have the firewall to contend with?` Without having any idea of the implementation of your school's firewall I couldn't say.  Your teacher should tell you what he expects of you.

Comment: I just want to know what kind of techniques do apps like skype or yahoo messenger or teamviewer use for communication. Because in most cases they do not require user intervention for setting. They do it automatically and i want to do the same.

Comment: @WinCoder Actually, when you use those applications you'll often be prompted by your firewall to allow access for those applications.  For many people's home PCs they won't even have a firewall.  For a school environment, they'll usually open up the ports those common applications use in anticipation of them being used.  Again, the point here is to find a port already opened by your school's firewall, not to bypass the firewall when it's trying to stop you.

Comment: Either run the client and server on the same PC, or build a VM and run the server on that. It will still work over the internet, if you didn't have the firewall in the way. The only other option I can see is to use a port that the firewall isn't blocking. There's no reason why you can't communicate on port 80 for example, as long as the server isn't also a webserver.

Comment: @Jay My client,server application works fine on localmachine. and wouldn't be port 80 blocked by other application such as a browser.

Comment: @Servy Ok but these application also use UPNP for port forwarding right ? or do they use some other technique ?

Comment: IIRC the TCP stack will forward the data to which ever app requested it. There are a few ports that are normally open, such as FTP, SSH etc. You're server can listen on any of those, as long as you never try to open a http/FTP/SSH session to your server machine it should work just fine. Can you not just use a local network? It will demonstrate that it could work over the internet, if the firewall weren't there.

Comment: @WinCoder It doesn't really matter, for your purposes.  All that matters is that you use a port/protocol that is whitelisted by your firewall.  This most likely means just asking your teacher/network admin what ports are open, as I'm sure that there is either a port, or a range of ports, open but not dedicated to anything.

Comment: i guess this issue of port forwarding is far more complex than i initially thought. Anyways my application works fine on local machine and i guess i will have to go with it.

Comment: @WinCoder What makes you think it's more complex then you thought?  I'm trying to tell you that it's *simpler* than you thought.  Your firewall is mostly just a big list of ports that are open and ports that are closed.  You need to use one that's open, and ideally one that's not also being used by some other program.  That's probably as simple as just asking your teacher which port you should use (given that it works locally).  What is complex about that?